# Fullscreen Still Has Taskbars at Top and Bottom

Tags: gnome-classic, fullscreen, taskbar

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and running the Gnome Classic desktop.  Whenever I go fullscreen, the taskbars at the top and bottom which hold the menus, notifications, etc. are still visible.  This only happens when I'm in a browser or trying to play a game.  I've tried it in both Firefox and Chromium, and get the same result no matter which one I use.  Videos I watch using VLC however do not have the bars at the top and bottom.

I found only one post about this in the questions, but there were no answers that worked for me.  I wasn't sure if commenting my problem into the 5 month old post would move it to the top where it could be seen, so I made this one.

Comment: Were you pressing F11 to full screen the window?

Comment: No, I've been hitting the fullscreen icon.  When I say "go fullscreen", I'm referring to the video itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Googling, I stumbled upon a fix for this problem.  Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oli/compiz-place-patch 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once all that gets done downloading and installing, restart your computer.  The bars at the top and bottom should now be absent when a video is fullscreen.

If this does not work for you, here is the bug report forum in which I found the answer.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/976032

It contains other possible solutions to this problem which may be helpful.